# How to combine multiple captures through 123D Capture?

Tags: autodesk

I was wondering if there is a way to combine multiple captures using either the ipad app or desktop application for 123D Capture through Autodesk. I want to take a capture of an object, flip it, take a second capture of the bottom of the object, and then combine the two captures so I have the entire object captured from every angle (top, bottom, sides).

Ideally after this I would see which sections of the object are blury and take new photos of those sections and manually stitch them on.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Check Autodesk ReCap, it can manipulate & handle point clouds

http://www.autodesk.com/products/recap/overview

Answer (score 0):

You can go even further to generate 3D models from these pictures with ReCap 360( http://recap360.autodesk.com). And it is also possible to do this with API, here are some samples on github (http://developer-recap-autodesk.github.io/)